# Best way to retrieve a List of int from a list of object[] in c#

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am trying to retrieve a list of IDs from a list of `object[]`. Here is my code:

```
private static List<int> getReceivedIds(object[] objectList)
{
    var received = new List<int>();
    foreach (object[] b in objectList)
    {
        if (b != null)
        {
            received.Add(int.Parse((b[0].ToString())));
        }
    }
   return received;
}
```

I am looking for a performance optimised solution for this code.

I changed the code to this:

```
    private static List<int> getReceivedIds2(object[] objectList)
    {
        var received = new List<int>();
        foreach (object[] b in objectList)
        {
            if (b != null)
            {
                received.Add((int)b[0]);
            }
        }
        return received;
    }
```

Also I compared the LINQ query and `foreach` statement performance and here is the result:
[Performance test results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjfgy.png)

The test shows that the `foreach` statement is 6 times faster than LINQ.

Anybody can improve the performance of this code?

Here is the code for my test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (int test = 0; test < 100; test++)
        {
            object[] objectList = new object[1000];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                objectList[i] = new object[] { rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000), rnd.Next(1, 10000) };
            }
            Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopWatch.Start();
            for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                getReceivedIds(objectList);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var t1 = stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

            stopWatch.Restart();
            for (int i = 1; i < 100000; i++)
            {
                getReceivedIds2(objectList);
            }
            stopWatch.Stop();
            var t2 = stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds;

            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("LINQ: {0}  -  ForEach: {1}", t1, t2));
        }
    }


    private static List<int> getReceivedIds(object[] objectList)
    {
        List<int> received = objectList.Cast<object[]>()
        .Where(b => b != null)
        .Select(b => (int)b[0])  // or Convert.ToInt32(b[0])
        .ToList();
        return received;
    }

    private static List<int> getReceivedIds2(object[] objectList)
    {
        var received = new List<int>();
        foreach (object[] b in objectList)
        {
            if (b != null)
            {
                received.Add((int)b[0]);
            }
        }
        return received;
    }
}
```

Comment: Define 'better'. You can use LINQ.. `var recieved = objectList.Cast<object[]>().Where(b => b != null).Select(b => int.Parse((b[0].ToString())));` - though I'd be hesitant to say it's better in this case.

Comment: is it working? are you getting any error? how your `objectList` looks like?

Comment: @un-lucky: It works but I am looking for better performance. `objectList` is an array of `object[]`. The first item of each `object[]` is an integer.

Comment: @Rob: I mean better performance. I am looking for the fastest way to do it.

Comment: @TechTotal Pretty much the only thing you can improve it not using object arrays, and as Tim Schmelter pointed out, not doing `int.parse(.ToString())`, but rather, casting to `int`

Answer (score 2):

If the first item in the `object[]` is actually an `int` you don't need to parse it, you can cast it. You could use this LINQ query if you want:

```
List<int> received = objectList.Cast<object[]>()
    .Where(b => b != null)
    .Select(b => (int)b[0])  // or Convert.ToInt32(b[0])
    .ToList();
```

Comment: @TechTotal: i doubt that the LINQ query causes the performance difference but that it doesn't need to convert the `int` to string and to parse the string back to `int`.

Comment: I was wrong about better performance with LINQ. There was a mistake in my performance test code. I gave to correct it. The LING query is 6 times slower than foreach statement. I will put the test code and the result on the question section for others.

Comment: @TechTotal: that i doubt also. I think you're measuring the wrong thing. How large is your `objectList` at all?

Comment: I test with 1000 items in the `objectList`.

Comment: @TechTotal: i still doubt that the LINQ approach is noticeable slower than the `foreach`, but since you're now using the `cast` instead of your old `ToString`/`Parse` approach you're already using the most efficient approach. You should show how you've measured, i'm fairly sure that you've done it incorrectly.

Comment: I added the code for the test to the end of the question. Please let me know if I am wrong.

Comment: @TechTotal: i'm suprised that the difference is so large. But actually your collection is not so large but you are using the method extremely often. If the collection was large and you would call this method only once the difference would be negligible. Now you are mainly measuring building the expression tree and executing the query.  The question is why you need to store them as objects at all. If you really need to call this method often because the collection changes continuously then you should use your `foreach`, otherwise you could store the result in a variable that you use later.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 int[] resultArray = Array.ConvertAll(inputArray, x => Convert.ToInt32(x));
```

Note : Ensure that the values are int.
For reference :[msdn link for ConvertAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx)